# Is it normal to say "Allow myself to introduce myself"?

Tags: pronouns, reflexives

When [Austin Powers says this phrase](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/myself)? [Is it considered to be somewhat of an exception to normal use, like with](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/myself://),

> Myself is often used where *I* or *me* might be expected,

Or was it more abnormal than that, and was just a joke? I'm not sure of other instances where it's used commonly in a similar manner.

Comment: Have you looked at other questions on the topic such as [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1176/when-is-it-correct-to-use-yourself-and-myself-versus-you-and-me) or [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/301265/allow-introducing-myself-vs-allow-me-introducing-myself) or done any other research beyond consulting a dictionary (which isn't a good source for grammar, compared to a grammar book)?

Comment: I know they are reflexive, but as the dictionary points out, there are common exceptions.

Comment: Both the links you provide lead to the dictionary. No, it is not 'fine' - see [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/301265/allow-introducing-myself-vs-allow-me-introducing-myself?noredirect=1&lq=1). Only you can 'allow yourself' to do something.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're saying. Are you saying the common "allow me to introduce myself" is wrong?  If you have an answer, can make an answer.

Comment: It's an answer and disallowed? What are you saying? It's a question about exceptions, not first time learners.

Comment: We are not supposed to 'answer' the question in a comment - but this is an English learner's question, so it should be migrated to English Language Learners and answered there. (No, I'm not saying that _Allow me to introduce myself_ is wrong!!)

Comment: I know, and yet people are answering in comments. The question is whether it falls under the exception or not. If you say it's not fine, then that may conflict with the definition given, unless you have a reason it doesn't. It's not clear what you're saying, you said it's not fine, then you said "Only you can 'allow yourself' to do something." so it sounds like you say it is ok.

Comment: This isn't about learning how to learn how to use myself, it's whether a definition fits.

Comment: Or you meant only 'you' can 'allow yourself'. Should be clear with quotations.

Comment: But yeah, if you say it's not fine, then the answer would explain why the definition does not fit in this scenario. The thing is, if people understand it, it works, even if it sounds funny. But then there is the question if this falls under normal and adnormal exceptions to it just being reflexive.

Comment: Austin Powers had a number of language quirks. Misuse of language is a common trope of characters trying to sound high-class.

Comment: Please rewrite this question so it is clear what you want. Does "commonly accepted grammatical error" mean something that many people don't think is an error (i.e. it's accepted as valid), or something that most people accept is an error? What is "did it just sound funny?" supposed to mean? Are you asking if it's a joke, if it's a funny joke, or if it sounds weird, odd, or abnormal? Clarify the question by editing it not by adding 20 or 30 comments.

Answer (score 4):

OK, since the moderators haven't migrated this, I'll risk incurring criticism and answer it.

He should have said "Allow *me* to introduce myself."

It doesn't make sense to ask another person to allow 'yourself' to do something - only *you* can *allow yourself* or, to put it another way, only *I* can *allow myself.*

Presumably the joke is that Austin Powers is supposedly a suave English gentleman, but here he uses bad English.

Comment: So you don't think it fits under the definition in the question, used where 'I' or 'me' is expected?

Comment: Note that M-W says "Critics have frowned on these uses since about the turn of the century". Opinions differ as to how acceptable it is to use _myself_ instead of _me_ in sentences like _Please return the completed forms to myself_.  See the first 'Linked' question in the right-hand column. But I don't think many people would consider Austin's line to be good English.

Comment: Ok that's question I had, sounds like it's a matter of opinion. To be clear, I was asking if it fits with the normal usage that critics have frowned on, or not. It sounds like they would call it bad English whether it was normal or not.

Comment: See also [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/600425/did-king-charles-iii-use-the-pronoun-myself-correctly?rq=1)

Comment: The joke is that Powers is a high-toned buffoon, not regal, elegant, or proper. His script is filled with such malapropisms.

Comment: If he's speaking to someone politely, they would be allowing **him**, and the mainstream usage is "Allow me to introduce myself". Anything other than **me** there is well outside the main channel, which is not to say "frowned upon".